# Bluetooth (NOT USB or WiFi) Nautilus Browsing of Android File System (Works With USB)

Tags: nautilus, bluetooth, android

The *salience* of this question is due to the fact that it is increasingly difficult to repair the USB port on smartphones without risking irreparable damage and this USB port is one of the most frequent causes of smartphone disposal.  In my case, I've purchased multiple wireless charging stations and installed Bluetooth on my Ubuntu system for the sole purpose of avoiding reliance on the phone's USB port so as to continuing using Nautilus as a way of managing files on my Android smartphone.

NOTE:  I *can* use a USB cable to `Nautilus`-browse my Android files IF I place such great stress on the USB connector to the phone that it threatens to do further hardware damage!  When the connector is so-stretched, the Android phone appears in the `Nautilus` file browser as expected but then disappears if the mechanical stress is not maintained at a dangerous level.

Having set the stage for justifying this question as not only unique but also *salient* for an increasing number of people:

The Android does appear in the `Settings->Bluetooth` devices and files successfully transfer to the Android.

```
sudo apt install nautilus-sendto
```

Is already at the latest version and restarting `Nautilus` doesn't help

```
sudo apt-get install android-file-transfer
```

Didn't help.  Nor did going into `~/Public` and installing the `Nautilus` plugin (since that is obviously only to provide access to Ubuntu's files not vis versa).

Comment: Does the phone support this?